# How to use non-privileged user to restart Apache

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

Using CentOS 7 AWS instance. I got the below problem in all the instances

```
===================================================
[oms.deployer.acc@********* ~]$ service httpd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
Cloud User (ec2-user)
oms.deployer.acc
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2):
===========================================================
```

I am trying from `oms.deployer.acc` which is a static user and also have wheel access.

I need to restart the httpd service with normal user.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the easiest way that will not suggest inventing a bycicle is going to be `sudo`. You still can provide user with limited number of commands, namely the `systemctl restart httpd` by using `visudo`

```
# visudo
```

add line like this:

```
nonprivuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart httpd
```

save file and test it:

```
# su - nonprivuser
$ sudo /bin/systemctl restart httpd
```

Comment: What does the `ALL=(ALL)` mean? For the command after the `NOPASSWD:`, should those be comma-delimited if you need to provide that user with multiple capabilities, or how do you list multiple commands out?

Comment: @Ungeheuer the first `ALL` is the tty. Meaning, user is allowed to work on any tty. Second `ALL` is _as user_, meaning, the user can work on any tty and run on behalf of all users. Everything that goes after this referst to commands. So root, for example, should have `ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` - he can work on _ANY_ tty, as _ANY_ user of _ANY_ group to run _ANY_ command. In my exacmple I replace the last `ALL` (any command) with the specific command. And you can use comma as a delimeter for multiple commands, eg. `NOPASSWD: commands1, commands2`

Comment: Thanks deimos! Excellent explanation. +1 from me